# System clock reset to Jan 2001?

Tags: hardware, battery

I got an error message saying something like "System clock reset to Jan 2001" and then many things stopped working. I has my laptop in standby mode and the battery must have gone completely flat whilst on standby. How would you go about fixing this and generally perform hardware troubleshooting on a Mac? (on a PC I'd look for the CMOS clock and battery, among other things..)

Comment: What's your Mac? Make, model and year please...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your PRAM/NVRAM battery is dead. The NVRAM (or PRAM for older Macs) is responsible for time and date settings, as well as other things (see [About NVRAM and PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379)).

iFixit is the place to look for guides and parts. [Here's](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Core+Duo+Model+A1150+PRAM+Battery/490/1) a guide on replacing the battery on a MacBook Pro 15" Core Duo.